# Straightforward way to get url minus querystring

Tags: python

Is there a more straightforward way to get the url without the querystring than the below?

```
>>> import urlparse
>>> url = 'http://yahoo.com/home/?site=new'
>>> parsed_url = urlparse.urlparse(url)
>>> url = parsed_url.scheme + '://' + parsed_url.netloc + parsed_url.path
>>> url
'http://yahoo.com/home/'
```

Comment: How about urllib? urllib.splitquery(url)

Comment: The query string always starts with `?`, right? So how about `url = url[:url.find('?')] if url.find('?')>0 else url`? You can compute `url.find('?')` first if you want to optimize.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use regex as

```
>>> import re
>>> url = 'http://yahoo.com/home/?site=new'
>>> re.findall(r'^[^?]+', url)[0]
'http://yahoo.com/home/'
```